# My non-inverting amplifier doesn't work correctly (the Gain isn't correct) [ICL7650S Op-Amp]

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, non-inverting

I'm working with [ICL7650S](https://www.intersil.com/content/dam/Intersil/documents/icl7/icl7650s.pdf)([online datasheet](http://html.alldatasheet.com/html-pdf/177437/INTERSIL/ICL7650S/385/1/ICL7650S.html)). I made a non-inverting amplifier but I don't know why the Gain isn't correct! this is my circuit:

[image: figure1]

[image: figure2]

[image: figure3]

The Gain should be (841k/2.14k)+1=393.99 but when I applied 6mv in the postive input I got 283mv and when applied 13mv, I got 584mv in the output. why?

**Edit1:** cirtuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffJTei.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**Edit2:** I measured the voltage of some parts and result:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHUFVE.png)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

The primary reason that you are not seeing what you expect is that you are trying to operate the part outside of its common mode range. This part is not a rail to rail op-amp. The common mode range from the data sheet is as follows:

[image]

When a +5V and -5V set of supplies is used.

Comment: I just changed the supply to 12.3v for +V and 0v for -V and applied 9mv to postive input and just got 428mv! and for 115mv got 4.55v.

Comment: Why not try a bipolar supply such as +/-5V? This will move your reference (GND) way away from the V- rail.

Comment: I just have positive supply and in my main circuit only should use positive supply.

Comment: The input range extends below the negative rail so this isn't the problem.

Comment: @MichaelKaras Please look at Edit2 in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see how you have the following connected in your pictures: -

[image]

It looks you are neither using an external clocking source NOR using the internal clock. It also looks like the two capacitors on pins 1 and 2 do not connect to ground.

Your circuit shows none of this and therefore is of no use.

Comment: As you can see in the pictures, I have connected two capacitors (two 100nf) to Cextb and CextA and they connected to Cretn. Why and how should I use the clock?

Comment: @Roh - Check your protoboard carefully. In the photo it looks like the Cretn wire is off by one row of holes at the common connection of the two capacitors.

Comment: @Roh you need to apply an external clock or use the internal clock by activating pin 14 correctly (from memory) Read the data sheet - this is the first thing you should do to understand what all the pins do.

Comment: @MichaelKaras Are you sure? look at these picture: http://img4.uplood.fr/free/5cpt_20150502_153725.jpg and http://img4.uplood.fr/free/fndm_20150502_153714.jpg and http://img4.uplood.fr/free/rmb8_20150502_153655.jpg

Comment: @Andyaka I applied Vcc to INT/EXT pin and nothing happened. I think when it is NC, it means it uses internal clock and no need to other pins.

Comment: @Roh - I just went by the picture in the posting. If you checked and it is connected right then all is well.

Comment: @Roh OK so what was the source of your input voltage and how sure are you that it was 6mV then 13mV? What are the pots doing? A full circuit diagram is very, very important.

Comment: The both pots are for making millivolts voltages. I measured the amounts by my digital multimeter. ok, hold on! to draw a complete circuit.

Comment: The INT/EXT port has a pull up resistor, to disable the internal clock you need to provide -vcc not vcc.However for a simple amplifier this port may be left open (as you have done) doubt this is the problem.

Comment: Plus according to the data sheet they mention that if you leave the port open (using the internal clock) the recommended capacitor value of 0.1uF (page 5).

Comment: @Roh P11 needs to be corrected.

Comment: @Andyaka Please look at Edit2 in the question.

Comment: this is so straightforward with the uA741 IC. Should ground be floating like that? I wonder what is causing it to behave that way. With 88mv at the Input theoretically it should be 34.7 V output, but its getting clipped (as expected) but at a lower value. I would expect it to give an output of about 5V.